# What is the advantage of cache mechanism change of Integer class in JDK 1.6 or above?

Tags: java, integer

I found cache mechanism is improved in jdk 1.6 or above jdk versions.

In jdk 1.5 the cache array in Integer is a fixed one, see

```
  static final Integer cache[] = new Integer[-(-128) + 127 + 1];
```

In jdk 1.6 or above version, an method named **`getAndRemoveCacheProperties`** and an `IntegerCache.high` property have been added to Integer class,

like,

// value of java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high property (obtained during VM init)

```
private static String integerCacheHighPropValue;

static void getAndRemoveCacheProperties() {
    if (!sun.misc.VM.isBooted()) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        integerCacheHighPropValue =
            (String)props.remove("java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high");
        if (integerCacheHighPropValue != null)
            System.setProperties(props);  // remove from system props
    }
}
```

With this change, **it is allowed to configure a highest value for cache and to use a new cache range.** (`-128 <= cachedValue <= highestValue`).

****Here are my questions:****

**Q#1** Why the cache range is using [-128 ~ 127] in jdk 1.5 or default cache of jdk 1.6 or above version? Is it just to support `bytes` and `char '\u0000'~ 'u007f'` ?

**Q#2** What is the advantage to specify a high value for cache range in jdk 1.6 or above version? What kind of appilication or sceen is suitable for us to do so?

Please help me out with these questions. Thank you very much in advance.

Below is the Source code for IntegerCache and valueOf(int i) in Integer class. It just for referance.

**jdk 1.5**

```
private static class IntegerCache {
private IntegerCache(){}

static final Integer cache[] = new Integer[-(-128) + 127 + 1];

static {
    for(int i = 0; i < cache.length; i++)
    cache[i] = new Integer(i - 128);
}
}


public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
final int offset = 128;
if (i >= -128 && i <= 127) { // must cache 
    return IntegerCache.cache[i + offset];
}
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

**jdk 1.6**

```
   private static class IntegerCache {
    static final int high;
    static final Integer cache[];

    static {
        final int low = -128;

        // high value may be configured by property
        int h = 127;
        if (integerCacheHighPropValue != null) {
            // Use Long.decode here to avoid invoking methods that
            // require Integer's autoboxing cache to be initialized
            int i = Long.decode(integerCacheHighPropValue).intValue();
            i = Math.max(i, 127);
            // Maximum array size is Integer.MAX_VALUE
            h = Math.min(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE - -low);
        }
        high = h;

        cache = new Integer[(high - low) + 1];
        int j = low;
        for(int k = 0; k < cache.length; k++)
            cache[k] = new Integer(j++);
    }

    private IntegerCache() {}
}


public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if(i >= -128 && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + 128];
    else
        return new Integer(i);
}
```

Comment: JDK 1.6 uses the fixed range, JDK 1.7 uses the dynamic range using `IntegerCache.high`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q#1 Why the cache range is using [-128 ~ 127] in jdk 1.5

Because that's the way they designed JDK 1.5.

> or default cache of jdk 1.6 or above version?

Because that's the way they designed JDK 1.6.

> Is it just to support bytes and char '\u0000'~ 'u007f' ?

In JDK 1.5, yes, in JDK 1.6+, no.

> Q#2 What is the advantage to specify a high value for cache range in jdk 1.6 or above version?

So that values in a wider range get cached.

> What kind of appilication or sceen is suitable for us to do so?

An application that frequently uses values in a wider range.

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons, it might be interesting to have higher values cached. Imagine you are working with a `List<Integer>` with intensive operations with numbers below 1000. Then it becomes quicker to use the cache instead of continuously creating Integer objects on the heap.

I must admit that I think that the use-cases are rather rare.

Answer (score 0):

```
> +
> + /**
> + * Cache to support the object identity semantics of autoboxing for values between
> + * -128 and 127 (inclusive) as required by JLS.
> + *
> + * The cache is initialized on first usage. During VM initialization the
> + * getAndRemoveCacheProperties method may be used to get and remove any system
> + * properites that configure the cache size. At this time, the size of the
> + * cache may be controlled by the -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size> option.
> + */
```

Taken from

[Integer Class JDK 7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/diff/4c3f752993a5/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java)